# How much privacy is one giving up when javascript is turned off?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, security, javascript

I was thinking about setting up Tor browser bundle to be my main browser and perhaps add a "open in chrome" (or something like) when I ran into an insurmountable Tor related problem. I hadn't considered this until now because everywhere seems to warn that one is giving up copious amounts of privacy by modifying Tor in any way. I thought I'd try in my regular browser testing on panopticlick with and without js enabled, disabled I'm a not great 1 in 14k, was 1 in 83k with default IE, 1 in 700 with my regular browser no js using Tor, with js and no Tor, well pretty darn unique...

My question is, if I am using Tor with javascript disabled, and something like "self destructing cookies" am I at significantly more risk? Another side to this is, how much benefit is there to regular browsing hiding ones location? with the slew of addons I have installed (checking it against things like browserspy.dk) it really seems like the main bit of ongoing information "leakage" left is my location, which coupled with my language does make me a bit unique but as I have cookies (LSOs included) regularly deleted) js disabled etc. that doesn't seem as "trackable". Last detail, when I am serious about anonymity, I do indeed boot up Tails and use that.

Comment: Honestly, I lack the information to really answer your question. However over all the years I have spent on TOR, it is always recommended to not have javascript enabled as it does pose a security/privacy risk. Through javascript, someone could determine much information about you such as IP and location, browser and OS.

Answer (score 1):

Check how much identifiable Information your browser sends with the EFF's [Panopticlick](https://panopticlick.eff.org/) project. Revisit with different settings/Plug-Ins/Add-ons to see the differences.
The lower your “uniquely identifyable in x” score, the less identifyable your browser is.